# View a PDF in WPF without using WindowsFormsHost

Tags: .net, wpf, pdf, windowsformshost

Are there any native WPF controls for displaying PDFs?  I am writing a program that will load a PDF file and then display extra notations on top of it.

Using a WindowsFormsHost (http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/) won't work because a WindowsFormsHost control always displays on top of all other WPF controls in a window.  This won't allow my notations to be seen over the PDF.

Converting the PDF into a raster image with the level of zoom detail that I need would create a file that is too large.

The WebBrowser control doesn't allow the pages to be changed or zoomed programmatically.  I also can't remove the Adobe toolbars.

Any third-party libraries I used would need to be free (as in beer).

Answer (score 7):

Provided that you have some PDF viewer plugin (such as Acrobat Reader) for IE on your machine...

```
    <Grid>
            <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser1"
                        Source="C:\Temp\Test.pdf"/>
    </Grid>
```

works just fine...

Comment: I tried this, but I can't seem to control the WebBrowser enough for my purposes.  See the update to my original question for more details.

Comment: @Eric K, What is it that you want to control? WebBrowser can be controlled... it provides its HTMLHost interface that can do wonders!

Comment: I need to remove all visible toolbars from the PDF ActiveX plugin.  I also need to be able to zoom the PDF.  And finally, I need to be able to navigate to specific pages.  I know that the WebBrowser has some page navigation, but it is specific to URLs and your viewing history.  It doesn't allow you to specify, for example, page 3 of a specific PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputations yet to make a comment, so I will put it as an answer.
I have had a very similar problem with Flash recently and I ended up using WindowsFormsHost and [Overlays/Adorners](http://www.nickdarnell.com/2009/12/wpf-overlay-control/). Just my 2cents.

Here is XAML creating an overlay as a popup window:

```
    <Grid>
       <Canvas >
        <WebBrowser  x:Name="wbMain" Width="800" Height="500"></WebBrowser>
        <Popup x:Name="puOverlay" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=wbMain}">
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="50" Name="headEllipse" Stroke="Black" Fill="Orange" Width="50" Canvas.ZIndex="5"/>
        </Popup>
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="50" Name="headEllipse1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Orange" Width="50" Canvas.ZIndex="5"/>
         </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

For the simplicity sake I reduced my overlay to one ellipse. Web Browser is hosted in WindowsFormsHost.
Here is the code placing and showing it:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        puOverlay.VerticalOffset = -60;
        puOverlay.HorizontalOffset = (wbMain.ActualWidth / 2) - 20;
        puOverlay.IsOpen = true;
        ...
    }
```

Pretty simple, however don't hesitate to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your example?  I'm having a bit of trouble getting the sample in your link to work correctly.

Comment: I tried using an Adorner by following the steps in this guide: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/ but the WindowsFormsHost was still drawn on top.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but using a Popup is different from the Adorner technique described in your link.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I forgot that I ended up using Popups as the fastest and the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any good royalty free 3rd party WPF controls that work well.  Telerik has a pdf viewer, but it doesn't do all types and won't do large documents well for me.  I tried Syncfusion's as well and that was buggy too.  I ended up using WindowsFormsHost with a another 3rd party GD picture's windows forms viewer.  They say they're making a WPF version though.

Now there are others that you have to pay for every server install that might be good, I just can't work with that though.